# Transformation of pan vector using SVG API

Tags: svg, 2d, coordinate-transformation, pan

I have an SVG `<path>` with points in "model" coordinate system. For simplicity let my path consist of `x, sin(x)` pairs - note the lack of any scaling and offsets.

To render it on screen I calculated a `SVGMatrix` and put it into `SVGTransformList` of my path element. Also I use CSS `vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke`.

Now I want to pan my sine chart using a mouse, so I got the shift vector in SVG screen coordinates.

My idea is to put one more matrix in my `SVGTransformList` and calculate it from the screen shift vector.

Should I put this new matrix before or after my original matrix? What is considered a good style? (I know that the coefficients of the second matrix will be different in the two cases)

Also to transform my shift vector to model coordinates I transform back two SVGPoints: zero and with coordinates of my delta vector, and manually subtract the images coordinate-wise. Is it the way to transform vectors, e.g. there are
no better math or API approach?

Comment: to the first question since matrix multiplication is non-commutative, it depends on what you want to achieve. There are APIs in the SVG DOM to do matrix transformation.

Comment: Yep since they are noncommutative the left-composed and the right-composed transformations to achieve the same net effect will be different. All I want to achieve is to drag with mouse (so chart is visually fixed on screen in relation to mouse pointer while dragging)

Comment: Show the code you have so far then.

Comment: I don't have any code. It's not a problem to make it working either way (pre- or post- composition). The question is which way is better and how do I generally apply camera controls in view pipeline, be it SVG or OpenGL or whatever. So it's more a general question of using coordinate transformations in graphics systems than a specific question of SVG. I can write the code to illustrate my question though, but I don't have it at hand (well, it's a big system and I don't have a self-contained fragment handy)